# Blog system in Firebase Hosting

Tags: firebase, url-rewriting, blogs, firebase-hosting

I discovered Firebase one month ago (or more) and loved its functions. I saw Firebase Hosting, that host pages. But, i have a question: it's possible to make my own blog system with Firebase Hosting?
And making a template URL for all blog pages:
`https://example.com/posts/<PostID>/comments`

Answer (score 1):

You can use a static site generator like [Hugo](https://gohugo.io/) or [Jekyll](https://jekyllrb.com/) to create a website like a blog.  After new posts you'll need to regenerate the site and upload (~2 command line commands).

I've done the above with [Hugo](https://gohugo.io/) and [Firebase hosting](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/) and my website/blog.

Answer (score 0):

You can develop a Blog System with Firebase. ;)

Src Code for the Blog is at my Stackoverflow task: [Create Firebase Blog Post with <iframe>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65792532/create-firebase-blog-post-with-iframe)

It is working fine. There is only a problem with posting frames